# Wie würde man Dashboard sinngemäß übersetzen

Tags: translation

Die wörtliche Übersetzung von *dashboard* ist ja Armaturenbrett. Das ist zwar korrekt, wenn man von Autos oder Bedientafeln spricht. Wie würde man es ins Deutsche übersetzen, wenn von Dashboard-Webseiten die Rede ist?

Ein Beispiel:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/dashboard/

**Update**
Unsere finale Lösung ist jetzt den Begriff **(Guthaben)verwaltung** zu verwenden.

Comment: Mhh... Bedienoberfläche?

Comment: Speziell für ein im Kontext der IT erfundenes oder neu interpretiertes Wort finde ich eine Übersetzung überflüssig und ich würde immer das Englische Originalwort bevorzugen. Es kann durch eine Übersetzung mit Pech sogar zu Missverständnissen kommen, wenn das englische Wort wesentlich verbreiteter als das (eventuell schlecht übersetzte) deutsche Wort ist. Muss das Wort übersetzt werden?

Comment: Bedienoberfläche ist eines dieser Worte, die -wenn sie in diesem Kontext benutzt werden- zu Missverständnissen führen können. Als Bedienoberfläche würde ich eher ein/das GUI im allgemeinen Bezeichnen und weniger ein Dashboard im speziellen.

Comment: @BenSower: das könnte auch eine gute Antwort sein, denn ein "Armaturenbrett für die Wörterpressenverwalter" kommt wirklich nicht so gut... ;)

Comment: _Schaltbrett, -tafel, -zentrale, Konsole_. Die Konsole ist im EDV-Bereich allerdings schon mit zwei Bedeutungen belegt, nämlich ‚Videospielkonsole‘ und ‚nichtgrafische Benutzeroberfläche; Kommandozeile, Terminal‘. _Kontrollzentrum_ habe ich in dieser Funktion durchaus schon gesehen, auch wenn es das sonst eher bei ESA/NASA gibt und nicht (nur) zum Kontrollieren, sondern zum (Fern-)Steuern und Einstellen dient.

Comment: Für einen Englisch-Muttersprachler, der neu im Computerwesen ist, ist das Wort Dashboard genauso befremdlich wie Schalttafel u.ä. Konstruktionen im Deutschen. Es herrscht aber unter Deutschen ein magisches Denken vor, dass im Englischen die Sprache vom Himmel fällt, direkt in die Köpfe von Engländern, Australieren, Amis und so weiter hinein, und dass die Kunstwörter, die dort genauso neu sind, oder 5-15 Jahre älter, es aber einst waren, quasi natürlich wären und einen magischen Mehrwert haben, der bei einer Übersetzung verloren geht. Deswegen solle man sie nicht übersetzen.

Comment: Ohne ein Guthaben zu haben habe ich dennoch bei Wordpress ein Dashboard. Guthabenverwaltung trifft es gar nicht.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also *falls* ich es überhaupt übersetzen wollte, dann wären vielleicht *Kontrollzentrum*, *Administrationsbereich* oder *Verwaltungsbereich* sinnvolle Begriffe, die in etwa das ausdrücken, was das (Wordpress-)Dashboard tut.

Comment: In diesem Fall ist es schwer zu sagen, ob einer der Begriffe komplett das Wort Dashboard übersetzen kann. Wenn es sich nur um eine Übersichtsseite handelt die nicht primär dem Management der Seite dient (z.B. es gibt Dashboards um Informationen wie Graphen usw. darzustellen), dann finde ich alle drei Möglichkeiten nicht sehr treffend. Ansonsten würde ich im zweifelsfall für *Kontrollzentrum* stimmen.

Comment: Naja, bei Wordpress werden hier natürlich auch neue Updates angezeigt und Statistiken, wieviele Kommentare/Spam, etc. erkannt wurden. Dennoch ist dies primär der Bereich, in welchem beispielsweise neue Beiträge verfasst werden können, aber auch Updates/Plugins, etc. eingespielt oder installiert werden können. Ich finde im übrigen auch "Dashboard" selbst keinen sonderlich passenden Begriff für ein Web-Backend.

Comment: Das ist auch kein Backend, sondern maximal ein Frontend fürs Backend...

Comment: @BenSower Im Allgemeinen bezeichnet man bei Shops oder CMS den Bereich als Backend, welcher nicht für den Kunden/Besucher ist, sondern für das Personal, welches die Daten pflegt. Und bei Wordpress ist das so genannte Dashboard das Backend.

Comment: Und wie wird dann der Server bezeichnet auf dem Wordpress läuft? 
Ich finde ein Backend sollte alles das sein, was einem Kunden (sei er normaler Nutzer oder Verwalter), nicht zu Gesicht kommen sollte. Aber ja, Backend ist sehr grob definiert und hat auch nichts mit der eigentlichen Diskussion zu tun.

Comment: @BenSower Naja, ich hätte dazu mal "Server" gesagt ;-) Ansonsten ist die Unterscheidung in Frontend und Backend eigentlich recht geläufig im Sinne von "Web-Seite für Konsumenten" und "Web-Seite für die Verwaltung". Aber es stimmt, mit dem eigentlichen Thema hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: "Backend" ist aber ein mindestens so gutes Beispiel wie "Dashboard" dafür, wie unterschiedlich man solche Begriffe übersetzen kann :-).

Comment: Da wir uns hier im Kontext einer in einen Kunden- und einen Administratorbereich eingeteilten Web-Anwendung befinden, finde ich sowohl Frontend, Backend als auch Dashboard relativ eindeutig definiert. Ich bin auch der Meinung, dass keiner der Begriffe übersetzt werden muss. Für die Diskussion Frontend/Backend/was ist der Server empfehle ich https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-End_und_Back-End. Diese Beschreibung deckt sich ziemlich mit meinem Verständnis und auch dem unserer Kunden (denn ich bin Informatiker).

Comment: Abhängig vom Kontext trifft das Wort *Übersicht* **manchmal** gut zu. Ansonsten sehr gute Vorschläge vom Antwortgeber.

Comment: Unsere finale Lösung ist jetzt den Begriff Guthabenverwaltung zu verwenden. Von daher ist der Vorschlag von @ThorstenDittmar von uns bedeutend gewesen.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit Bedienfelder/tasten. Allerdings würde ich ein paar solche Felder oder Tasten nennen, damit der Leser auch weiß, was gemeint ist.

Comment: Finde ich unpassend, weil es auch um Anzeigen geht, nicht nur um Tasten.

Comment: Es ist eine ganze Seite voller Felder, Buttons und Steuerungselemente.

Answer (score 0):

Grundsätzlich gilt für Fachbegriffe, dass man mit ihrer Übersetzung vorsichtig sein sollte. Bei den meisten Auditorien sollte man einfach den Anglizismus verwenden, *Dashboard*.

Falls man partout eine Verdeutschung braucht, weil man zu einem Auditorium spricht, das sich mit Anglizismen schwertut, würde ich *Kontrollzentrum* oder *Steuerungszentrale* verwenden. Diese Begriffe beinhalten, dass Informationen aus der Peripherie eines Systems zusammenfließen, dass dort  entscheidungsrelevante Informationen dargestellt werden, und dass dort auch Entscheidungen getroffen, Einstellungen geändert werden können.

Comment: Danke ChatGPT für den identischen Input, wie Dittmar vor 10 Jahren.

Answer (score -1):

Vielleicht ganz simpel als Pinnwand, also als eine Art erste Anlaufstelle.

Heutzutage sehr gern verwendet für Administrationsbereiche. Und eine Pinnwand ist auch eine erste Anlaufstelle, um sich gewisse Infos anzeigen zu lassen.

Answer (score -3):

Bei Stefan Raab hieß das Dashboard *Nippel*. Ich lege mich für die Antwort also auf *Nippel-Brett* fest. Da können die Webadmins dann gepflegt abnippeln.

Man könnte aber der Einfachkeit halber einfach mot *Übersicht* hantieren, oder *Konsole*, wo konsolidiert wird, anscheinend *das Saldo* betreffend.

Answer (score -5):

Ist Dashboard der Software nicht im Grunde ein „**Zeigwerk**“, da es aus Systemfunktionen irgendwas zusammen***werkelt*** (z. B. Benutzerfunktionen, Benutzerverwaltung, Neuerstellung von Seiten, Verwaltungsdinge usw.) und dies übersichtlich aufbereitet darstellt, also an***zeigt***, oder?

Einen Übersetzungsvorschlag, den ich zum Anstoß geben will, ist:

- Deutsch: Zeigwerk (im Allgemeinen) oder „erstelle XYZ-Zeigwerkzeug (im Engeren)“
- english: dashboard (in general) or „create XYZ-dashboard (in particular)“

Ausführlichere Gedanken dazu siehe:

- https://wiki.opensourceecology.de/Hilfe_Diskussion:%C3%9Cbersicht_von_Begrifflichkeiten_in_einheitlicher_Sprache#Dashboard_Uebersetzung_Zeigwerk

Comment: Was ist denn bitte ein "Zeigwerk"? Ich denke nicht, dass es sinnvoll ist, den Fragestellern ein selbst ausgedachtes Wort, was niemand versteht und nirgends belegt ist, vorzuschlagen - außer auf einer selbst angelegten "Diskussionsseite" (das unterstelle ich bei der Namensähnlichkeit/gleichheit mit dem Autor der Diskussionsseite jetzt mal).

Comment: Ich möchte es zum *Anstoß* geben, ob man es blöd bewertet oder nicht, es sei ein Anstoß, das Denken anstoßen! Technischer Beispielsatz, den auch meine Eltern verstünden: *„Im Zeigwerkzeug Benutzerverwaltung können Sie Benutzer einschränken, hinzufügen oder filtern usw.“* – Mit Dashboard können meine Eltern nichts anfangen, das ist der Punkt, hingegen bei Zeigwerkzeug (s. Beispielsatz) können sie sich die Bedeutung und Funktion erschließen, ich habe es ausprobiert ;-)

Comment: Ob "Eltern [damit] nichts anfangen" können, ist schwerlich der Punkt, oder? Die Eltern (von denen ich unterstelle, daß sie vermutlich keine Mathematiker sind), können wahrscheinlich auch mit "Kohomologie" nichts anfangen, trotzdem käme niemand auf die Idee, das mit "Gemeinsamkettenzusammenstellung mit Gruppengleichgestaltigkeit" einzudeutschen. Nur in der Informatik soll jeder, der in der Lage ist, einen Berechner mit Kleinweich Fenster einzuschalten, jeden Fachbegriff verstehen müssen.

Comment: Interessanterweise sind allerdings immer nur die englischen Fachbegriffe "unverständlich" - keiner weiß (angeblich), was ein "Filesystem" ist, aber "Dateisystem" ist OK. Wäre nicht "Sachverhaltszusammenstellungsanordnung" noch viel verständlicher?